# Installing SDK on Windows 7

Tags: windows, android-sdk

I have downloaded the SDK from [Andriod site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) on a system where 32bit Windows XP is installed. Now I am trying to install this on system where 32bit Windows 7 is installed and this pc is without internet access.

The installer is not doing anything on double clicking on SDK Manager, no SDK Manager related Service is running on Task Manager. **Can you please suggest me, what I need to follow to install Andriod on Windows 7?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to download and install the SDK on a machine which is comparable to the target machine. In this case, install the SDK on a machine with Windows 7, and not with XP (Also, because XP is risky due to [end of life](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx))

Then copy the `android-sdk`-Folder to your target machine.

Then you should siply be able to launch it with a double-click on the SDK-Manager.

**However**, if this doesn't work, try to [execute the SDK-Manager as "Administrator"](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html)

Also, if this fails, try to connect the Windows 7 computer to the internet and then download it properly as described here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

If this is also impossible, try to give aditional information (where do you have the SDK from? Is it the latest version? Where did you put it on the Target Machine? etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, downloaded it directly from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html in Windwos 7 and it worked. However root cause is unknown behind the issue.